# Devise login issue when cookies disabled in browser

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5

When cookies disabled in browser, devise sign in not working.

Submitting a form through ajax and skip authentication token in controller.

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

User was updated(current_sign_in_at, last_sign_in_at,..) when submit form but not logged in browser.